# How do I randomize the values in the (question_options) array and display them using radio buttons for a specific test?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm having issues randomizing the values in this array and displaying them for a specific test, using radio buttons. I want to randomize it so that the answers wouldn't appear in the same place for other questions.

```
let wrong_answers = [1990, 1991, 1992, 1994];

let right_answer = [1993];

let question_options = [test.right_answer].concat(test.wrong_answers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below snippet.

```
var arr = ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'answer4'];

let correct_answer = ['answer3'];

let question_options = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

// verify answer! Assume user passes 'answer' value using radio button as answer

correct_answer[0] === answer ? true :
```

Let me know if it is the way you wanted! I hope it'll help you.

Comment: I want to return all the values in the array randomly,  when I print it.

Comment: Can you put an example to understand the problem clearer? I am feeling I'm missing a simple thing!